# How to display Users name by their email login?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to code for school where we have to have someone login to a database by entering a valid email that is in the database and then display that user first and last name based on the email that they entered. I can get them to login with the email but I cant figure out how to display the names.

Heres an exerpt from my index.php controller

```
else if ($action == 'register_product') {
$email = $_POST['user_email'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email='$email' ";
$result = $db->query($sql);

$customerID = get_customer_by_email($email);
$firstName = $customerID['firstName'];
$lastname = $customerID['lastName']; 
}
```

and heres my Register form where the names will be displayed, thanks!

```
<h2>Register Product</h2>
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="register_product_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_product">

     <label>Customer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="category_id" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>"
           readonly><br>
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: I see you make a query (a very dangerous one, subject to SQL injection), but then you are not  using the result.  You also are referencing a function named get_customer_by_email($email), but you didn't include that code. Can't help without relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the user information in `session` after they log in !

```
<?php
// Start the session at first 
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
.
.
.



$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email='$email' ";
$result = $db->query($sql);

$customerID = get_customer_by_email($email);

$_SESSION['user_data'] = $customerID;
```

now you can use session to get user data in every page :

```
 <label>Customer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="category_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']['first_name'] ?>"
           readonly><br>
```